# Insert "http" image in MigraDoc table

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

MigraDoc provides insertion of image when it's in application directory. 
Example:

```
Section section = document.AddSection();    
section.AddImage("../../SomeImage.png");
```

When I add http image path in .AddImage parameter it displays "Image not found." in PDF.

Is there any way to insert http image in PDF generated by MigraDoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot insert images via a HTTP reference.

Download the image to a local folder and add this local copy to the MigraDoc document.

When using PDFsharp, you don't need a local file; an Image object can be used instead.

Code for XImage.FromURI can be found here (for PDFsharp):
http://forum.pdfsharp.de/viewtopic.php?p=4851&sid=4898a4ff0b0437cfdbb80bc48bdfed36#p4851

Code that allows MigraDoc do use dynamic images (no temporary local file needed) can be found here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.de/viewtopic.php?p=4123&sid=4898a4ff0b0437cfdbb80bc48bdfed36#p4123

Update:
With PDFsharp 1.50 beta 2 and later it is easy to add images you have in memory (byte[] or such). If you only have an HTTP reference, you still have to download the image yourself. But you no longer need a temporary file or a patched MigraDoc version.
[More information on the MigraDoc site](http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx)

The trick is simple: convert your image to a string and pass that as a filename with the "base64:" prefix.

```
static string MigraDocFilenameFromByteArray(byte[] image)
{
    return "base64:" +
           Convert.ToBase64String(image);
}
```